# How to get a dictionary from two uneven lists, grouping all values for the same keys and not removing any value?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Suppose,

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The available ways to combine these two lists give the following:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(dictionary) # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
```

I want the result as `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [3,4]}`
(grouping all values for the same keys and not removing any value). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Did you try anything? Do you _really_ want an output where some keys are lists and others are not?

Comment: Yes, I want to.

Comment: please check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327247/how-to-create-dictionary-from-two-lists-without-losing-duplicate-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327247/how-to-create-dictionary-from-two-lists-without-losing-duplicate-values) You can find a answer.